# KNIME - Draw Pyramid with IDs

Tags: excel, automation, draw, knime

i created some multi level reviews for my webpage which are stored in excel with the following format:

| ID | URL | Text | Link | Link-ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | pyramid.wordpress.com | new search engine | duckduckgo.com | 0 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 100 | mysearchengine-pyramid.blogspot.com | new pyramids | pyramid.wordpress.com | 10 |
| 101 | mysearchengine-pyramid.blogger.com | here | pyramid.wordpress.com | 10 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |
| 1000 | blogworldwide.domain.com | my search pyramid | mysearchengine-pyramid.blogspot.com | 100 |
| 1001 | blogs.webdomain.com | my friend | mysearchengine-pyramid.blogger.com | 101 |

My goal is to visualize which links / domains link to every layer (which domains link to Link-ID 10, which to Link-ID 100 / 101).

My idea was to create something like a mindmap / pyramid chart (example here: https://share.sketchpad.app/23/867-3bff-16396f.png) with knime, but my experience with it is not that good.

Thanks for help :)

Comment: So what is the code you use, why are you not content with it?

Comment: Hey, what you mean?

Comment: You say *"My idea was to create something like a mindmap/pyramid chart with knime, but my experience with it is not that good"*
So what was your try and where did you get stuck? The idea is that people here can help you from there, not create code for you.

Comment: yes, i need only some hints to get started with this